# Not all is? or not all are?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, subjects

Not all countries _________ to produce high quality product.

a) can
b) is able
c) are able
d) been

Comment: In *Not all countries **can** produce high quality product*, we don't include the "infinitive marker" ***to*** before the infinitive verb ***produce*** (but it ***is*** required with the semantically equivalent ***are able***). Also note that singular ***product*** here is a "domain-specific jargon" form mainly confined to people working in marketing (and hack reporters writing about such things). The rest of us talk about plural *high quality **products***.

Comment: Gotcha! Please help me with this one as well. His words were very __________. A) offending  B) offensive

Answer (score 2):

"countries" is plural, so we use "are" here.